# Is an offer of a discount an acknowledgement of guilt of negligence and misconduct?

Tags: evidence, civil-procedure, acknowledgement

I have the following excerpt:

> I have looked at the bills related to the service calls and can offer discount.

This party is being sued for negligence and misconduct in providing services. However, they are denying the allegations. Does the above excerpt show that they are acknowledging that they are guilty? What is the significance of that statement in a court claim against this party?

Additional context:
This is an excerpt from a reply to a request to cover the amount of damage. The full explanation lists a couple of factors, but the party does not take the responsibility. At the end of this explanation, they offer the mentioned discount.

Comment: The substance of the [added paragraph](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/58659/3) can be inferred from your initial post, whence the edit really does not add context. But since you already got two upvoted answers which fairly address your question, you might want to post a new question rather than making the authors revisit their answers to catch up with subsequent edits. Be sure to include sufficient detail of communications/documents as well as other relevant facts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not an acknowledgement of guilt or liability. It offers a "discount" some sort of reduction in price. This could be an offer of settlement without admission of liability, or even just advertising for repeat business (unlikely as that may seem). Without the rest of the communication, there is no way to tell. Unless there are specific admissions, this statement alone is not likely to have much significance in such a case.

**Edit**: There is still not enough context to tell exactly what the sender of this communication wanted to accomplish with the offer of the discount, but since the OP now says "the party does not take the responsibility" this is **not** an admission of guilt, whatever else it is. It sounds like some sort of backdoor form of settlement offer without admission, but that is far from clear to me. My original answer is not significantly hanged here.

Comment: This could not even be an offer of settlement. This may or may not be an offer of settlement.

Comment: @Emma As I said, it might be an offer of settlement or something else. Without more context, there is no way to tell.

Comment: That's not true. It means exactly what it says. It says `[I] can offer discount`. There is no mention of settlement.

Comment: @emma It doesn't say why the discount is being offered (nor how much). The discount might be offered by way of settlement. Or for some other reason. There is no way to tell without more of the communication.

Comment: Because the matter is extremely common and that's how businesses react towards such customers. They can bring millions of why in the Court (no one knows). The word `looked at` means nothing. All judges know that.

Comment: Regardless, your answer is correct. It's `No`.

Comment: Added some more color. Please let me know if this changes the situation.

Comment: Can someone please edit the 9 out of communication?  Silly 10 character limit is keeping me from doing it.

Answer (score 1):

#### DISCLAIMER

- I'm not a Qualified Judge or Lawyer; and
- This answer is not a legal advice, includes solely unqualified opinions for informational purposes.

---

#### No.

- [This answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/58660/24670) is correct.
- It is just a casual business communication.
- There is no significance here, whatsoever.
- Based on the information that you have provided, the case would be dismissed, unless you have other types of evidence or other similar statements.

---

#### Edit

No. Because:

(a) "the party does not take the responsibility"; and
(b) their statement does not mention anything about settlement, nor does it refer to.

Therefore, the case would be dismissed.

---

Comment: Added some more info on this. Does it change anything?

Comment: @AK88 Updated for that. Is a small claims court case?

Comment: I don't see a reason to conclude that the case would be dismissed. The OP has not detailed the nature of the claims nor the evidence supporting them. They may be clearly valid, or not at all. All that we can tell is that this communication is not an admission of fault. That does not mean that the original case is without merit, simply that it will not be decided on the basis of an admission, at least not on this communication.

Comment: @DavidSiegel We answer questions based on the fact(s) and opinion(s) in the question. I see no reason at all that the case would proceed (based on the materials in the question).